# ECMAScript object spread/rest - assigning to multiple properties at once

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-next, ecmascript-2017

The new object rest/spread syntax has some surprisingly nice applications, like [omitting a field from an object](https://codeburst.io/use-es2015-object-rest-operator-to-omit-properties-38a3ecffe90).

Is there a (proposed) way to also assign to several properties of an object, the values from variables with the same names? In other words, a shorter way to say:

```
o.foo = foo;
o.bar = bar;
o.baz = baz;
```

Note: Without losing the existing properties of `o`, only adding to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Object.assign`:

```js
const o = { initial: 'initial' };
const foo = 'foo';
const bar = 'bar';
const baz = 'baz';
Object.assign(o, { foo, bar, baz });
console.log(o);
```

Note that both shorthand property names and `Object.assign` were introduced in ES6 - it's not something that requires an extremely up-to-date browser/environment.

Something similar that *reassigns the reference to the object* would be to initialize another object by spreading `o` *and* list `foo, bar, baz`:

```js
let o = { initial: 'initial' };
const foo = 'foo';
const bar = 'bar';
const baz = 'baz';

o = { ...o, foo, bar, baz };
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const foo = 'foo';
const bar = 'bar';
const baz = 'baz';
const o = {foo, bar, baz};
console.log(o);
```